# Perform an assignment in an IF conditional in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, if-statement, assignment-operator

Is there a way to set a variable in VB.NET in an IF statement. I would like to do the following:

```
If (TypeOf sender Is TabControl And TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage) Then   'tab control is adding a tab page
    AddControl(CType(e.Control, TabPage))
ElseIf (TypeOf sender Is TabPage) Then                                  'tab page is adding some control
    AddControl(CType(sender, TabPage), e.Control)
ElseIf (tabPageFound = FindTabPageOf(sender)) IsNot Nothing Then
    tabPageFound.SomeAction()
End if
```

Is there some way I can get the last "ElseIf" to work? I know I can re-write it to get it to work but is there some syntax that will make it work the way it is?

Comment: (Before people throw too much of a hullaballoo: this is perfectly valid approach in C# *if* `tabPageFound` is not initialized beforehand or assigned afterwards.)

Comment: From the perspective of someone who has often had to support other people's code, I _highly_ recommend not doing this in any language.  Conditional statements should examine state, not change state.

Comment: What would you suggest David ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use VB.NET (so mind the syntax errors). However, note that each "else if" can be trivially rewritten as an "else" with a nested "if". Many languages, such as those based on the C-syntax, do not have a compound "else if" statement but have nicer support for "hanging if" statements.

In this case it might be rewritten as:

```
If (TypeOf sender Is TabControl And TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage) Then
    ...
ElseIf (TypeOf sender Is TabPage) Then
    ...
Else
    tabPageFound = FindTabPageOf(sender)
    If (tabPageFound) IsNot Nothing Then
        ...
    End
End If
```

Just something to consider.

---

For the sake of completeness this shows removal of all `ElseIf` usage and the resulting nesting:

```
If (TypeOf sender Is TabControl And TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage) Then
    ...
Else
    If (TypeOf sender Is TabPage) Then
        ...
    Else
        tabPageFound = FindTabPageOf(sender)
        If (tabPageFound) IsNot Nothing Then
            ...
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

No, Visual Basic does not support that syntax.

Your only option is to pass the variable byref to a method that will assign it and return the appropriate value.

For example:

```
Function DoFindTabPageOf(ByRef tabPageFound As Control, sender As Object) As Control
    tabPageFound = FindTabPageOf(sender)
    Return tabPageFound
End Function
```

Then your ElseIf becomes:

```
ElseIf (DoFindTabPageOf(tabPageFound, sender) IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: Now ... that is just scary. While I sometimes use the "equivalent of the post" in C#, *I would flat-out reject this approach*. It is too hard to see what is going on, especially with no required annotation at call site (which differs from C#). That being said, it's technical correct, so +1.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree, I would never, ever write this as production code. However, it is the only way to get the OP's desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I know this calls the FindTabPageOf twice, but can be done as below. It becomes more harmful if you want to use the tabPageFound further somewhere.

```
If (TypeOf sender Is TabControl And TypeOf e.Control Is TabPage) Then   'tab control is adding a tab page
    AddControl(CType(e.Control, TabPage))
ElseIf (TypeOf sender Is TabPage) Then                                  'tab page is adding some control
    AddControl(CType(sender, TabPage), e.Control)
ElseIf (FindTabPageOf(sender) IsNot Nothing) Then
    FindTabPageOf(sender).SomeAction()
End if
```